# TensorFlow: best method for non-one-hot vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Currently I have a CNN predicting classes fed with one-hot `y_train` vectors like this:

```
[ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0. ]
```

So `np.argmax(y_train)` would return 5, since this is the right class.

Unfortunately I have far to less training data for the network to classify my test data correctly. The training error gets better over time, but I think this is overfitting. The test error is always really bad.

I thought a normal distribution would make the network's life easier, so instead of saying class 5 is the only right class and all other classes are equally wrong, I want to give the network a high penalty if it predicts class 0 instead of 5 but just a small penalty if it predicts 4 instead of 5. I thought `y_train` for vectors encoding class 5 could look like this then:

```
# values are rounded for displaying them in one line, original vector
# is always full tf.float32
[ 0., 0.,0.004, 0.054, 0.242, 0.399, 0.242, 0.054, 0.004, 0., 0., ]
```

The question is, **which method for calculating the cost would be appropriate?**

Would:

```
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_net, y_train)

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

Still produce reasonable results, even if the `y_train` vectors aren't one-hot encoded anymore?

Or does this require stronger architecture changes? Currently I have two Conv/Pool-Layers and two fully connected ones. The output is simply `y_net = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2`, since `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` applies the softmax.

My actual architecture has an output of 800 dimensional output vectors, so having very few training data for now the network nearly never manages to hit one single class out of 800 correctly in the test data, only in the training data (with overfitting).

However, I would be totally ok if the network predicts the class in a range like +/- 20. So if class 400 is the right one, predicting a class between 380 and 420 would be enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` should support your use case, according to documentation.

Since you are fine with predicting in a range +/- 20 and not necessarily the exact labels, then maybe a better loss would be appropriate. For example, MSE between the target *value* (e.g. 400) and your prediction (e.g. 420)? This part sounds more like a research question than related to TensorFlow.

Comment: Yeah, it could be considered more of a research question than simple implementation. However, do you have some experience with TensorFlow? So would this approach be reasonable or does a better idea come to your mind? Could you supply a concrete example with MSE? I think I did not quite get your point by now.

Comment: The simple thing you could try is:
`y_net = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2`  # y_net would be 1-dimensional instead of 800-dim
`loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_net - y_target)))`

With this, you'd like y_net to produce a number that would be as close to 400 as possible with the y_target equal to 400. You might also want to normalize the values so that the maximum values for the target come from a reasonable range (like -5..5 instead of as large as 400)

Comment: Exactly @Rafal. if the classes have a logical order set it up as a regression problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I would be totally ok if the network predicts the class in a range like +/- 20. So if class 400 is the right one, predicting a class between 380 and 420 would be enough for me.

I think the obvious thing to do here is to make your labels more coarse, i.e. if you're predicting depth values you can have 100 different values instead of 800.